Is there a way to send emails in bulk to people that has booked a "Google Calendar Bookable Appointment Schedule"?
I want to send an email in BCC to each of the guests that have booked an appointment via a relatively new feature in Google Calendar called "Bookable Appointment Schedule".
This feature, same as other types of events, collects emails of your guests so that the host can send them updates.
The problem is that the guests email list is hosted in Google Calendar, which only allows hosts to send an email to everyone without the option to Choose BCC, and without the option of personalising the email usign each guest's first name.
My question is wether there is a way to extract the guests list of any Bookable Appointment Schedule from our google calendar via script and drop it to a spreadsheet, from where being able to send BCC emails in mass.
Thank you

Creating a Spreadsheet that lists all the Guest of an Event.
For the sake of simplicity of the solution I will create simple requirements for the solution. This is going to use an Apps Script Solution.
Requirements:
Pre-Created Google Sheet. You need to get its ID. You can get it from Google Sheet's URL you can read more about this here.
You need to get the calendar ID which is usually your email depending on the situation and the event ID which is actually on the Troubleshooting Info of your event.

Note: Please take note that there is a programmatic way of getting this information. This is just to show you the simplest form to getting your desired list. Please feel free to raise any questions.

Sample Code:
function myFunction() {
  var cal =CalendarApp.getCalendarById("Your Calendar ID");
  var event = cal.getEventById("Your Event ID");
  const guestList = event.getGuestList();
  var guests = []

for (const guest of guestList){
  guests.push([guest.getEmail()]);
}
console.log(guests)
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Target Sheet ID");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,guests.length,1);
range.setValues(guests);
}

Photo Reference:

References:
Calendar App
Calendar Events
Spreadsheet Services

Thanks for you reply. The Event is actually a Bookable Appointment Schedule, so the way to get its ID is different since I don't find the "Troubleshooting" section of Appointment Schedules.  By editing it it shows a long ID in the URL but the script doesn't recognise this ID. So, how can I get the ID for this kind of events? Thanks

@VíctorEnrich it would be helpful if you provide a [mcve] that describes what you are doing so that we might be able to see a better way to help you.

Google Calendar has a new feature which are Bookable appointment schedule, which differ from regular events. I think the best for you to identify the ID of Bookable appointment schedules is to create one yourself in your google calendar to see how this kind of events are managed differently from regular events
